# Make Rest API call from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a Rest api with address http://mywebapi.xyz.com/foo which supports http post.

with request payload

```
{

    "text": "Foo", 
    "username": "anika",
    "icon_url": "bar"
}
```

How can i make this call from Mssql2012 DB  , i will prefer to not use a CLR procedure if other ways exists.

## edit

i have searched all over so and can only see suggestions of using a CLR sp to achieve this.

Comment: hi bridge, that is not a duplicate, that question those not have a marked answer, and those suggest using a CLR, which i want to avoid completely

Comment: It might be possiblt to use CURL.exe to interact with a restful web service. http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-test-a-rest-api-from-command-line-with-curl/ You can call CURL.EXE using `xp_cmdshell`, but this is often more frowned upon than `CLR`. Your best bet is to have an external service, or maybe a recurring SQL Agent job, or maybe just an exe that reads and write to a SQL queue table.You write your request to the queue table and the external process picks it up and writes the response back. Do any of those appeal?

Comment: @Edwin the top answer suggests not using the CLR - use service broker instead.

Comment: o.k team i may be forced to check out clr route based on @Nick.McDermaid suggestion, service broker sounds quite complex

Comment: Service broker would be the 'enterprise' approach to this. It's basically the proper way to process a queue. But you're right it is *waaay* complicated